# delete item out of firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I have a restaurant bookmarks list in my firebase, but I don't know how to delete a specific restaurant in my database.

So I have the function `unfavorite(favorite)` where I pass the favorite restaurant as a parameter. Till here, than I want to pass this parameters id to the query to remove from the database like this:

```
this.afDb.list(`bookmarks/${user.uid}/restaurant/${favorite.restaurant.id})`).remove();
```

here is a screenshot of my database list:

[image]

How can I remove that specific restaurant out of the bookmarks list?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking, currently your code is missing some parts because I can see that have two auto generated keys but you only list one after bookmarks but be slightly more specific so I can understand your problem below.

Comment: bookmarks/user.uid/AutogeneratedKey this is how it is stored now

Comment: Ok, so you're asking, "how can I delete that "AutogeneratedKey" key node when I know the "id" (child) within it?"

Comment: yes :) thats exactly what i am asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will first need to add an `".indexOn": ["id"]` rule to your database something like this:

```
"bookmarks": {
  "$user_id": {
    // normal reads and write rules here
  },
  ".indexOn": ["id"]
```

This step is necessary for firebase database because otherwise you wont be able to use the `orderByChild()` and `equalTo()` methods.

Then, where you have your delete function, you want to instead use:

```
exampleRef = yourDb.ref("bookmarks/${user.uid}"); //this is just to simplify your reference a bit 
exampleRef.orderByChild('id').equalTo(theDeleteIDhere).once('value').then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach((restaurant) => {
        restaurant.ref.remove();
    });
}); //this is a Promise that you can modify to return "true" if successful for example
```

The example I provided is just the way I have done it before (i.e. I prefer to use promises; hence the `then()` becuase this makes it easier to return that promise in an angular service which allows me to check whether the request was successful). You can use any variation of this so long as you have the "indexOn" rule and you use any sort of "sorting" method firebase provides [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)

**Method 2**
When I wrote this I totally glanced over the ability to map your restaurants like such:

Lets say your project is already listing those restaurants. You can therefore save each restaurant's auto generated id to a variable or map:

```
restaurants; // this is a map like this <your-identifier:autoID>
```

you can then easily just call:

```
exampleRef.child(restaurants[yourIdentifier]).remove();
```

Comment: Because I wrote this off the top of my head, let me know if what I have written brings up an error (though it shouldn't) so I can edit my response properly.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when I added that indexOn like you say I can never bookmark multiiple restaurants and just delete one?

Comment: You'll want to loop over the child nodes that the query matches: `exampleRef.orderByChild('id').equalTo(theDeleteIDhere).once('value').then(snapshot => { snapshot.forEach(restaurant => { restaurant.ref.remove(); } })`

Comment: Will look into it tomorrow thanks for you quick responses!

Comment: Done. But even if there was a single result, the loop would still be needed. A list of one item, is still a list.